# Any workaround to do yearly statistics for non tabular data with `tidyr` or `dplyr`?

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation, tidyr

I have a gridded data in `csv` file where yearly precipitation observation for all grids is stored in plain text data ([raw gridded data is right here](http://jmp.sh/v/n1C6Ky4R8YtjpPjQ2P9N)). However, I want to do yearly statistics for this grid data, to calculate yearly total precipitation for each grid cell. Because the size of raw data is rather big, I put this grid data on the fly ([please take a look raw gridded data on the fly](http://jmp.sh/v/n1C6Ky4R8YtjpPjQ2P9N)).

Basically, based on yearly precipitation observation, I want to do simple statistics, to calculate yearly total precipitation for grid cell all along the whole coverage. Here is whole grid coverage that I am gonna compute yearly statistics for its each grid cell.

[image]

I think `dplyr` or `tidyr` could help for this data aggregation. Perhaps the first thing to do would be to reshape the raw data in `csv` and get long spreadsheet for each grid' coordinate and simply use `base::sum` or `dplyr::summarize` utilities to do yearly statistics. To do so, here is my first attempt to get long spreadsheet:

```
raw_csvData %>% 
    group_by(.$days) %>% 
    tidyr::spread(spread(key = .$days,value = precip))
```

getting long spreadsheet for each grid, above R scripts doesn't work. Perhaps, getting long spreadsheet is not necessary to do, maybe there is even fast and smart way to get this done.

basically, I intended to calculate yearly total precipitation for each grid cell and add this aggregation result into new column meanwhile drop all daily observation data because I don't need that data once I get yearly total sum precipitation for each grid, which would produce even clean and smaller output.

If I don't need to reshape raw data in `csv` to get long spreadsheet, what's the efficient and fast run solution for this data aggregation task? Any nice way to make this happen with `dplyr`, `tidyr` or vice-versa? Any idea?

Comment: `data.table` is pretty fast at aggregating stuff. I know that's not what you asked, but have you tried it?

Comment: Assuming each lat,long pair is a single grid id, first convert your dataset to `data.table` then try, `p1980<-raw_csvData[,.(Net_precip=sum(precip)),by=c('long','lat')]` should give you the net rainfall per grid for 1980 for the file you've shared. Took 40ms to execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update** (per comments)
If you only need the annual total precipation and long/lat, and nothing else, use `group_by` and `summarise`:

```
raw_csvData %>% 
  group_by(long, lat) %>%
  summarise(total_precip = sum(precip))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   long [1]
   long   lat total_precip
  <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl>
1  6.12  47.4         846.
2  6.12  47.6         847.
3  6.12  47.9         852.
4  6.12  48.1         860.
5  6.12  48.4         867.
6  6.12  48.6         899.
```

**Original** (for adding column to existing data frame)
You can remove `days` with `select(-days)`.
Then `group_by` `long` and `lat` and compute grouped sums.  Use `mutate` instead of `summarise`, which will add the sum column back into your original data.

```
raw_csvData %>% 
  select(-days) %>%
  group_by(long, lat) %>%
  mutate(total_precip = sum(precip))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 7
# Groups:   long, lat [6]
   year month   day  long   lat precip total_precip
  <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>        <dbl>
1  1980     1     1  6.12  47.4   0.           846.
2  1980     1     1  6.38  47.4   0.           846.
3  1980     1     1  6.62  47.4   0.           846.
4  1980     1     1  6.88  47.4   0.           844.
5  1980     1     1  7.12  47.4   0.           853.
6  1980     1     1  7.38  47.4   1.20         880.
```

Comment: I tried `data.table` solution : `data.table::setDT(raw_csvData)`;  `p1980<-raw_csvData[,.(Net_precip=sum(precip)),by=c('long','lat')]`, and it produced exatly what I want. Any way to refine your solution in `dplyr` as well? Thank you

Comment: Sure - can you help me understand what's wrong with my current solution?

Comment: seems your output is not what I want, I need yearly total `precip` for each grid, and that `data.table` solution is correct. you could open `raw_csvData` on the fly ([raw csv data](http://jmp.sh/v/n1C6Ky4R8YtjpPjQ2P9N)) . I am expecting only grid coordinate pair and its yearly sum `precip` that would be in the final output. Any further update from you? Thanks

Comment: Ok, sure - but that's not what you asked for in your post.  You wrote "...and add this aggregation result into new column", which is what my solution does.

Comment: Just switch from `mutate` to `summarise`, then you're done.  See updated answer.